# query for all rows and indicate which ones have a certain text in a column

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to query a table to get all the rows, but also return which ones match a string search.

For example, here is what the table would look like.

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | foo |
| 2 | bar |
| 3 | foobar |
| 4 | moo |
| 5 | cow |

And I want to query and indicate which ones contain "foo". The query result might look like the below. The 'containsString' could be 0|1 or null|id, just something to indicate that the row contains the string "foo".

| id | title | containsString |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | 1 |
| 2 | bar | 0 |
| 3 | foobar | 1 |
| 4 | moo | 0 |
| 5 | cow | 0 |

The backup strategy is to query for all results and then programmatically Map over it. But I am hoping to do it in SQL.

Here is my first stab at it, but didn't work because it only returned the rows that contained 'foo'

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t1.title, t2.id as containsString 
FROM `news` t1, `news` t2
where t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN news t2 ON 
WHERE t2.title LIKE '%foo%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE WHEN` like:

```
SELECT id, title,
CASE
    WHEN title like '%foo%' THEN 1
    
    ELSE 0
END as comtainsString
FROM news;
```

Answer (score 0):

Chetan method in this case works, but another method is to first make a table with all the have a foo in their name, and union it with the others:

```
select * 
from
    (select *, 1 as containsFoo
     from table
     where title like "%foo%") as T1
    union
    (select *, 0 as containsFoo
     from table
     where title not like "%foo%")
  order by id;
```

Comment: Though the answer will fetch you the same result, the performance also needs to be checked. This query with `UNION` will require Two sequential scans over the entire data whereas the `case-when` will do it in single scan.